# An HVAC technician spilled pvc primer in the attic while working. It stained and wet sheet rock. Will it dry? Or ruin sheet rock?

Tags: hvac

HVAC technician spilled pvc pipe primer on sheet rock ceiling.  It caused a purple stain and wet halo. Will it dry? Or damage sheet rock?

Comment: How did he spill on the ceiling?   Did he spill it and it is seeping through the ceiling?  Is the ceiling painted and it's showing through the paint?  A few more details will help .

Comment: Yes, left purple stain and wet halo. HVAC Tech was installing pvc pipe for vent in attic. The can tipped over and not properly capped.

Comment: The purple stain went through painted ceiling in bedroom.The stain and wet halo shows on non painted sheet rock in attic.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [register](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting responses as answers can result in an automated lock that would prevent others from assisting you.

Answer (score 3):

PVC primer is primarily a mixture of volatile solvents, so it will dry, (considerably faster than water) leaving a purple stain.

I can't find any commentary from gypsum manufacturers on solvents other than water damaging gypsum, but that may be primarily since it's a relatively rare issue - assess the area for any signs of damage beyond turning purple when it has dried. The solvents may well have damaged the paint in the room below, as well as the dye staining it.

Alternatively, since this should be getting repaired by the installer's liability insurance, insist on having the affected area replaced, given limited to no data on solvent (other than water) damage to drywall - it's a trivial amount of extra work, given the need to repaint the ceiling in any case - and it is probably going to be easier to paint a patch of new drywall than to cover that purple stain with paint to the point that you can't see it.

Comment: Yes, I will probably have to replace the drywall. Thank you for response.